# почему программа не выводит True или False?

Tags: python

```
def isPrime(number):
    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2, int(number/2)+1):
            if (number % i) == 0:
                return False
                break
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False

isPrime(8)
```

Comment: Потому что в этой программе нет ничего, что заставило бы программу что-то выводить

Comment: как это исправить?

Comment: print...........

Comment: В интерактивном питоне `ipython` либо в ячейке `Jupyter Notebook` - этот код выведет `False`. А если в обычном питоне запустить, то ничего не выведет, потому что тут нет `print` результата вызова функции.

Answer (score 2):

Просто вы не сделали ни одного print() в программе --> вывода нет.

Надо сделать

```
    def isPrime(number):
        if number > 1:
            for i in range(2, int(number/2)+1):
                if (number % i) == 0:
                    return False
                    break
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    
    **print(isPrime(8))**
```

Или если понятнее , то

```
    def isPrime(number):
        if number > 1:
            for i in range(2, int(number/2)+1):
                if (number % i) == 0:
                    return False
                    break
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return False
    
    **result = isPrime(8)
    print(result)**
```